# How can I install Ubuntu on my PPC?

Tags: powerpc

I want to install 14.04 LTS on my Power Pac PowerPC. Where do I find the mirror to download the proper version?

Answer (score 0):

You can find PPC images on the cdimage site:

> The cdimage server also hosts releases of other Ubuntu images not found on this server, such as builds for less popular architectures and other non-standard and unsupported images. For Ubuntu Desktop and Server on popular architectures, please see the links above instead.
>
> - [Unsupported Ubuntu Images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/)

<sup>[releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)</sup>

However I was unable to find a PPC desktop image, only server.

Answer (score 0):

For PPC, I'd recommend the LXDE version of 14.0.4

There are PPC link on [this page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/trusty/release/)